# Matplotlib - Legend of a specific contour at different instants

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I m trying to plot a figure with a specific contour line (level = 320) at different times that is why a loop is used. 
I would like plot a legend with labels to specify the time during the loop as here :

[image]

A part of my code is shown :

```
cmap = plt.cm.hot

instant = 0
for instant in range(0,Sigma_stockMAX.shape[2]):

    name = 'test'

    VM_MAX_eq = 1./np.sqrt(2)*np.sqrt((Sigma_stockMAX[:,2,instant]-Sigma_stockMAX[:,3,instant])**2 + (Sigma_stockMAX[:,3,instant])**2 + (-Sigma_stockMAX[:,2,instant])**2 + 6*Sigma_stockMAX[:,5,instant]**2)


    VM_MAX_eq_interpolate = interpolate(VM_MAX_eq, vtx, wts).reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[0])

    plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)

    contour = plt.contour(XX_field[20:480,20:480], YY_field[20:480,20:480],ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(VM_MAX_eq_interpolate[20:480,20:480], 5),colors=(cmap(instant/ np.float(Sigma_stockMAX.shape[2])),),levels = [320],linestyles=('-',),linewidths=(2,))

plt.savefig(name+ '_0' + test[instant][81:110] + ".png", dpi=250)
```

I tried to add in the loop this part but it doesnt work :

```
labels = ['line1', 'line2','line3','line4',
           'line5', 'line6', 'line6', 'line6', 'line6', 'line6']

for i in range(len(labels)):
    contour.collections[instant].set_label(labels[instant])
```

Answer (score 1):

I used: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

```
cmap = plt.cm.hot
lines = []
labels = []
i = 0
instant = 0
for instant in range(0,Sigma_stockMAX.shape[2]):

    name = 'test'

    VM_MAX_eq = 1./np.sqrt(2)*np.sqrt((Sigma_stockMAX[:,2,instant]-Sigma_stockMAX[:,3,instant])**2 + (Sigma_stockMAX[:,3,instant])**2 + (-Sigma_stockMAX[:,2,instant])**2 + 6*Sigma_stockMAX[:,5,instant]**2)

    VM_MAX_eq_interpolate = interpolate(VM_MAX_eq, vtx, wts).reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[0])

    contour = plt.contour(XX_field[20:480,20:480], YY_field[20:480,20:480],ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(VM_MAX_eq_interpolate[20:480,20:480], 5),colors=(cmap(instant/ np.float(Sigma_stockMAX.shape[2])),),levels = [320],linestyles=('-',),linewidths=(2,))
    lines.extend(contour.collections)
    labels.extend(['line'+str(i+j) for j in range(len(contour.collections))])
    i += len(contour.collections)
plt.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper center', shadow=True)
plt.savefig(name+ '_0' + test[instant][81:110] + ".png", dpi=250)
```